# What are the units and axes directions for View.getLocationOnScreen ()?

Tags: android

View.getLocationOnScreen() returns the X and Y coordinates of a View.

- Are the units pixels, or DIPs?
- Where is the origin? Top left?
- Which corner of the View does the location refer to?
- Which way do the axes go? e.g. what are the coordinates of the four corners of a 320x480 screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getLocationOnScreen() returns coordinates relative to the screen (you can think of this as absolute position).  They are in pixels, the origin is top left, X axes increases to the right, and Y axes increases to down that's true for either orientation (portrait or landscape).  On a screen that is 320x480 they are:

- top left = 0, 0
- bottom left = 0, 480
- top right = 320, 0
- bottom right 320, 480

The other method getLocationInWindow() returns coordinates relative to the parent window (say a dialog, or something like that).  The coordinate system doesn't change, although the extents of what the range is depends on the size of the window your view is contained within.